Gauge field vacuum structure and winding number
I am studying vacuum structure of gauge field and winding number, following Tong's lecture notes here, with equation 3.13, with transformation matrix of $g^n$, I think we get the winding number of $n^3$, not just $n$ (because there are three derivatives).
How can I understand the winding number is exactly the integer $n$?
